# Timeout Error with "Unspecified" and "-shared-00-00" in endpoint

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following code for setting up and querying a collection:

```cs
var connectionString = $"mongodb+srv://{databaseSettings.User}:{databaseSettings.Password}@{databaseSettings.Cluster}.mongodb.net/{databaseSettings.Name}?w=majority";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseSettings.Name);
_guildResponsesCollection = database.GetCollection<GuildResponse>("responses");

var filter = Builders<GuildResponse>.Filter.Eq("guildId", guildId);
try
{
  var guildResponsesCursor = await _guildResponsesCollection.Find(filter).FirstAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e);
  throw;
}
```

the `FirstAsync()` call times out with this error:

> A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/CLUSTERNAME-shard-00-00.CLUSTERDOMAIN.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/CLUSTERNAME-shard-00-00.CLUSTERDOMAIN.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

I replaced the names CLUSTERNAME and CLUSTERDOMAIN above in case they're sensitive, but the rest is exactly what I'm getting. I think the two things that stand out to me are the `Unspecified` and the `-shard-00-00` in the endpoint, particularly as my connection string is being correctly built and passed into the `MongoClient` constructor, and I didn't specify anything about sharding. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: 1. Make sure that you use correct connection string, you can ask atlas to generate it to ensure. 2. Look at https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/

Comment: 3. `particularly as my connection string is being correctly built and passed into the MongoClient` - this says nothing until operation executing. 4. `and I didn't specify anything about sharding` - the endpoint you see has been created during srv resolving

Answer (score 0):

The fix was a simple one - I hadn't added my IP in the Network Access section.